Ethernet problems on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Before anything, I'm using a somewhat old Asus laptop model (Q550LF). With that said here is the more detailed specs of the problem:



We appreciate the effort you went through in order to post screenshots, however output of commands should be posted as text whenever possible; please also post the output of lspci -k by editing your question: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1510218/edit so that we can see exactly which drivers you're using

Are you trying to use the wired NIC named enp2s0? Or the wifi? It looks like the wifi has a connection. Exactly what isn't working correctly?

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
